# Reemplazar los NAs por la media de su columna en R

Tags: r, bucle-for, rstudio, replace

Tengo un conjunto de datos en el que algunas de sus columnas son numéricas, en esas columnas numéricas existen valores NAs y lo que necesito es reemplazar cada uno de esos NA con el valor de la media de la columna en la que se encuentra. No llevo mucho tiempo usando R y según lo que he investigado lo que quiero se podría hacer con un `for` que vaya por cada columna o con `laply`, y esto es lo que tengo:

```
for (i in 1:ncol(indicadores_BD)) {
  indicadores_BD[is.na(indicadores_BD[,i]),i] <- mean((indicadores_BD[,i]),na.rm = TRUE)
  }
```

Pero con este `for` tengo 2 problemas, el primero es que no sé cómo decirle que esto lo haga **sólo para las columnas de tipo numérico**, y el segundo es el siguiente:

```
Error in `[.data.table`(indicadores_BD, , i) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'i' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..i]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

Por otro lado, con `laply` tengo esto que ví en un ejemplo:

```
lapply(indicadores_BD, mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace(indicadores_BD, is.na(indicadores_BD), mean(!is.na(indicadores_BD)))))
```

Pero tengo el problema de que me sale esto

```
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : 
  no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "function"
```

No sé si exista una forma más fácil de hacer lo que quiero o qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal con `for` y `laply`, pero llevo ya horas varado con esto y en serio agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que estás usando `data.table`, francamente no lo he usado practicamente nada, pero lo que si puedo decirte que estás tratando en algunos lugares al objeto `data.table` como si fuera un `data.frame` y las mecánicas de indexación no son las mismas, por ejemplo:

Esto que es totalmente válido en un `data.frame` clásico:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
indicadores_BD[1,x]

Error in `[.data.table`(indicadores_BD, 1, x) : 
  j (the 2nd argument inside [...]) is a single symbol but column name 'x' is not found. Perhaps you intended DT[, ..x]. This difference to data.frame is deliberate and explained in FAQ 1.1.
```

No lo es en un `data.table`

Suponiendo que tu idea es trabajarlo como un `data.frame` clásico, (de última podrías convertir la base mediante `as.data.frame()`), supongamos unos datos como los que nos comentas:

```
set.seed(2020)
merge(
  matrix(sample(LETTERS, 50, replace = TRUE), ncol =  5),
  matrix(sample(c(runif(50), rep(NA,25)), 50, replace=TRUE), ncol = 5),
  by=0
) -> indicadores_BD
indicadores_BD

   Row.names V1.x V2.x V3.x V4.x V5.x      V1.y      V2.y      V3.y      V4.y      V5.y
1          1    L    M    B    N    R 0.6510358 0.6726305 0.7972218 0.5088476        NA
2         10    Q    C    O    V    B 0.6829807        NA        NA 0.1673671 0.3938651
3          2    W    X    X    G    J 0.2339084        NA 0.2082511 0.6829807 0.8844366
4          3    V    H    H    T    F        NA 0.3875929 0.9925618 0.4284416 0.6510358
5          4    X    J    D    R    O 0.2952934 0.8844366        NA 0.3623707        NA
6          5    A    R    R    T    K 0.6875061 0.2339084 0.5998948 0.2082511        NA
7          6    Q    P    N    U    M 0.4702981 0.4284416        NA 0.5998948        NA
8          7    D    V    N    T    X 0.7261997        NA 0.1568812 0.2952934        NA
9          8    J    B    L    P    M 0.5472646 0.6875061 0.2502319 0.1833963 0.1631660
10         9    F    P    P    L    M 0.4243989 0.1720709        NA 0.6510358        NA
```

En `data.frame` con columnas de distinto tipos y en las numéricas, algunos `NA` que queremos reemplazar por la media de dicha columna.

En primer lugar necesitaremos saber cuales son las columnas numéricas:

```
columnas_numericas <- which(sapply(indicadores_BD, is.numeric))
```

Aplicamos `is.numeric` a cada columna y no quedamos con el índice de las columnas numéricas. Lo siguiente es calcular la media de cada columna numérica:

```
cols_mean <- rep(NA, ncol(indicadores_BD))
cols_mean[columnas_numericas] <- colMeans(indicadores_BD[, columnas_numericas], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Lo único particular, es que que nos interesa que la media respete la cantidad de columnas totales del `data.frame`, por lo que habrá varios `NA` que corresponderán a las columnas no numéricas, y ahora sí, simplemente haremos una sustitución de valores `NA` por las medias correspondientes

```
for (x in columnas_numericas) {
  indicadores_BD[is.na(indicadores_BD[,x]), x] <- cols_mean[x]
}
```

Finalmente:

```
   Row.names V1.x V2.x V3.x V4.x V5.x      V1.y      V2.y      V3.y      V4.y      V5.y
1          1    L    M    B    N    R 0.6510358 0.6726305 0.7972218 0.5088476 0.5231259
2         10    Q    C    O    V    B 0.6829807 0.4952267 0.5008404 0.1673671 0.3938651
3          2    W    X    X    G    J 0.2339084 0.4952267 0.2082511 0.6829807 0.8844366
4          3    V    H    H    T    F 0.5243206 0.3875929 0.9925618 0.4284416 0.6510358
5          4    X    J    D    R    O 0.2952934 0.8844366 0.5008404 0.3623707 0.5231259
6          5    A    R    R    T    K 0.6875061 0.2339084 0.5998948 0.2082511 0.5231259
7          6    Q    P    N    U    M 0.4702981 0.4284416 0.5008404 0.5998948 0.5231259
8          7    D    V    N    T    X 0.7261997 0.4952267 0.1568812 0.2952934 0.5231259
9          8    J    B    L    P    M 0.5472646 0.6875061 0.2502319 0.1833963 0.1631660
10         9    F    P    P    L    M 0.4243989 0.1720709 0.5008404 0.6510358 0.5231259
```

Comment: Me funcionó perfectamente y entendí el código, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Mas sencillo es con package tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

#en valor_mean cálculo el promedio sin tener en cuenta NAs

```
valor_mean <- mean(dataframe$variable_X, na.rm = TRUE)
```

#luego tomo la columna y le digo que reemplace los NAs por valor_mean con los #decimales que necesites. En este caso redondea el número. No necesitas loops

```
dataframe$variable_X <- round(dataframe$variable_X %>%
                                  replace(is.na(.),valor_mean), digits = 0)

dataframe$variable_X
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma, de más alto nivel, usando `dplyr` es mediante el verbo `mutate_if()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

indicadores_BD %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(replace_na(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

Comentarios:

- Esta solución es consistente con `data.tables`
- Módificamos todas las columnas que sean numéricas, reemplazando los valores `NA` por la media de dicha columna, el `.` en el contexto del `mutate` es el comodín para indicar la columna en particular.

Y si quieres una solución aún más específica, tienes el paquete `naniar` especializado en el tratamiento de valores faltantes, que tiene mucha funcionalidad entre otras cosas para imputarlos, por ejemplo `impute_mean_if()`:

```
library(naniar)

indicadores_BD %>% 
  impute_mean_if(is.numeric)
```